# Correct way to strip off member function

Tags: c++

I have a simple IO class with thread safe getters and setters.
It looks like this:

```
template <class IO>
class LIO : public LThreadSafe
{
    public:
        LIO() {}
        IO getValue()
        {
            this->lock();
            IO ret = value;
            this->unlock();

            return ret;
        }
        void setValue( IO newval )
        {
            this->lock();
            value = newval;
            this->unlock();
        }

        LInput<IO> *toInput()
        {
            return (LInput<IO> *)this;
        }

    private:
        IO value;
```

Some classes need to be able to both read and write to these IO.
While others should only be allowed to read.
So I created an Input class which i can cast my IO class to

```
template <class IO>
class LInput : public LThreadSafe
{
    public:
        LInput() {}
        IO getValue()
        {
            this->lock();
            IO ret = value;
            this->unlock();

            return ret;
        }

    private:
        IO value;
```

Is this good practice? 
It seems excessive to create a whole new class for this.

**Solution**

I ended up going with multiple inheritance. Will check back on this thread once I've gotten more familiar with shared_ptr and C++ in general. 
Wish I could press the up arrow more times...

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time someone creates a new interface that is *smaller* than an existing one, e.g. `std::queue`, `std::ofstream`, etc.

Comment: Can't you just make your getValue() function const, then pass const references to the classes that can only read.  They won't be able to access setValue() since it's not const.  (Your locking mechanism would need to be mutable for this to work, though)

Comment: @benjymous: And that wouldn't even be abuse of `const` since it is a pretty good model of what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can think of, there are two ways.

### Use Sub-Class

You can make `LInput` private inherit from `LIO`, but mark input methods as public:

```
template <typename IO>
class LIO : public LThreadSafe
{
public:
    LIO() {}
    LIO(const LIO& in) { /* make a copy for read-only */ }
    LIO(LIO& io) { /* make a copy for write-only */ }

    shared_ptr<LInput<IO>> toInput() const { return make_shared<LInput<IO>>(*this); }
    shared_ptr<LOutput<IO>> toOutput() { return make_shared<LOutput<IO>>(*this); }
};

template <class IO>
class LInput : private LIO
{
public:
    LInput(LIO<IO>* pio) : LIO<IO>(*pio) {}
    using LIO<IO>::getValue;
};

LInput<int> in;
auto v = in.getValue();        // OK

in.setValue(xyz);              // Error: inaccessible
LIO<int>& io = in;                  // Error: inaccessible
```

Give this solution a second thought, you will find it's good when the IO object can be copied; if it cannot be copied, you will need to wrap the implementation class reference inside `LIO` class.

**If you cannot copy**, a complete example would be:

```
template <typename IO> class LIOImpl {};

template <typename IO> class LInput;
template <typename IO> class LOutput;

template <typename IO> class LIO {
  shared_ptr<LIOImpl<IO> > pimpl_;

public:
  LIO() : pimpl_(make_shared<LIOImpl<IO> >()) {}
  LIO(const LIO &io) : pimpl_(io.pimpl_) {}

  IO getValue() const { ... }

  LInput<IO> toInput() const { return LInput<IO>(*this); }
  LOutput<IO> toOutput() { return LOutput<IO>(*this); }
};

template <class IO> class LInput : private LIO<IO> {
public:
  LInput(const LIO<IO> &io) : LIO<IO>(io) {}
  using LIO<IO>::getValue;
};

template <class IO> class LOutput : private LIO<IO> {
public:
  LOutput(LIO<IO> io) : LIO<IO>(io) {}
  using LIO<IO>::setValue;
};
```

---

### Use Multiple Inheritance

The C++ STL `iostream` use the multiple inheritance way to implement the `istream` and `ostream`. The constraints is pulled up in the hirarchy. This *diamond inheritance* sometimes is considered as a bad practice.

This push down constraints method avoids *diamond inheritance*.

You can also use *diamond inheritance* using pure class as interface:

```
template <typename IO>
class LInput
{
public:
    virtual IO getValue() const = 0;
};

template <typename IO>
class LOutput
{
public:
    virtual void setValue(const IO& v) const = 0;
};

template <typename IO>
class LIO : public LInput<IO>, public LOutput<IO>, public LThreadSafe
{
public:
    IO getValue() const override { ... }
    void setValue(const IO& v) const override { ... }

    LInput<IO>* toInput() const { return this; }
    LOutput<IO>* toOutput() { return this; }
};
```

---

Choose the way you feel good, in the meantime, try to isolate your interface from implementation. Once you reach the limitation, (or your just don't like it any more) you can change the interface easily without re-implement.

BTW, if you are using C++ 11, you should use [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of hand writting `lock/unlock` pairs:

```
{
    lock_guard<LThreadSafe> lock;
    // ok you have lock now.
} 
// here lock is automatically released
```

Comment: Never seen the "using" keyword being used like that.
Thanks for that. Is my typecast in LIO::toInput ok?

Comment: No, you cannot typecast that way. Because the `this` may not be a LIO. I will make it like `LInput* toInput() const { return new LInput(this); }` Also, define a copy constructor for `LIO` so the new will like `LInput(LIO* pio) : LIO(*pio) {}`. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @XinHuang 'return new Something' is no good, better return std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr (C++11, boost otherwise)

Comment: Problem is that I can't work on a copy. The IO class gets its value updated in one thread and read as an input in another.

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks for reminding. I'm just following poster's style and try not to make too much noise.

Comment: @John I thought about that. So you will need to use [PImpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) to isolate the implementation from interface, and then you can make copies of `pimpl` pointers via a `shared_ptr`. Or else you can go the second way, but be more careful.

Comment: Are the typename <typename IO> lines correct in the "if you cant copy" section?

Comment: @John Sorry, seems the compiler inside my brain is not functioning very well. Replaced with a compiled version.